# C passing struct type to function inside that same structure

Tags: c, function, struct

I've been experimenting with structs in C and tried to make a simple struct with students where a struct is created and then we put some data inside the struct and so on this is the code. The goal is to inside the `struct Estudante` have a function pointer to the function `calcularMedia` but I want to pass to that function an argument of that same structure type.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome[20];
    char turma[10];
    int idade;
    int notas[10];
    int media;
    int (*calcularMedia)(Estudante estudante);
} Estudante;

int calcularMedia(Estudante estudante) {
    int media = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(estudante.notas); i++)
        media += estudante.notas[i];
    return media;
}

int main() {
    Estudante estudante1;

    strcpy(estudante1.nome, "Bernardo");
    strcpy(estudante1.turma, "10ºF");
    estudante1.idade = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        estudante1.notas[i] = 10;

    printf("A media do %s é %d\n", estudante1.nome,
           estudante1.calcularMedia(estudante1));
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to pass the struct inside the struct has an argument

Comment: You need to set correct function pointer value to the function pointer variable, before you can use the function pointer value:
    estudante1.calcularMedia = calcularMedia;

Comment: OT: `sizeof estudante.notas` is 20 or 40... You mean `sizeof estudante.notas / sizeof estudante.notas[0]`

Answer (score 6):

The type-alias `Estudante` is not created until after the structure itself has been defined, so it can't be used inside the structure itself.

But there is a simple way to solve it: Use a structure tag name (e.g. `struct Estudante`) and use that for the argument type:

```
typedef struct Estudante {
    // Other members...
    int (*calcularMedia)(struct Estudante estudante);
} Estudante;
```

Note that it's perfectly fine to use the same name for both the structure tag and the type-alias, because structure tag names are in a separate namespace.

If you really want to use the type-alias instead, then you need to use *forward declaration* of the structure, with a tag name, to define the alias:

```
typedef struct Estudante Estudante;
struct Estudante {
    // Other members...
    int (*calcularMedia)(Estudante estudante);
};
```

---

On a different note, I recommend that you pass a *pointer* to the structure to the function, to avoid creating a copy of the structure.

If the function is not supposed to modify the structure, then pass a pointer to a constant object:

```
typedef struct Estudante Estudante;
struct Estudante {
    // Other members...
    int (*calcularMedia)(const Estudante *estudante);
};
```

And as mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75555126/c-passing-struct-type-to-function-inside-that-same-structure#comment133301491_75555126) you need to assign to the function pointer inside the structure before you can use it:

```
estudante1.calcularMedia = calcularMedia;
```

Otherwise you will use an *uninitialized* pointer, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Oh, and the loop

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(estudante.notas); i++)
```

is wrong. The `sizeof` operator returns the size in *bytes*, not in elements. To get the number of elements, divide the total size with the size of a single element:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(estudante.notas) / sizeof(estudante.notas[0]); i++)
```

Comment: Worth to note that redefinition of the type alias is allowed only since C11.

Comment: @tstanisl I've updated answer to remove the extra  `typedef`.

Comment: Damm man, thank you very much for the help, gave me a much better understanding of what the hell I'm doing

Answer (score 2):

Use a tagged struct:

```
typedef struct Estudante{
    char nome[20];
    char turma[10];
    int idade;
    int notas[10];
    int media;
    int (*calcularMedia)(struct Estudante estudante);
} Estudante;
```

If you want to write:

```
int (*calcularMedia)(Estudante estudante);
```

instead (without the struct keyword), then with a tagged struct, you can also typedef before the struct type is completed:

```
typedef struct Estudante Estudante;
struct Estudante {
//...
};
```